# How do I resolve a StreamCorruptedException when serializing my Java object?

Tags: java

I apologize since I've seen postings on this topic but none seem to resolve my issue. So I'll try to be very specific. I am receiving a `StreamCorruptedException` when I try open an `ObjectInputStream` on my `ByteArrayInputStream`

I need to output an object (`X509Certificate`) to an XML file. My serialization code looks like the following:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputSream(bos);
  oos.writeObject(x509.getData());    // x509 is a DOM Element
  oos.close();
  bos.close();
```

The XML document appears to be just fine. My input code looks like:

```
  // elem is a DOM Element with contents placed in Context
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                    elem.getTextContext().getBytes())
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
  X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) ois.readObject();
  ois.close();
  bis.close();
```

The stack trace I'm getting is mostly through my own code and nothing internal to the JVM so it's hard to trace.  Here's what it is:

```
  java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5B0A5B0A
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader (ObjectInputStream.java:783)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:280)
  . my code
  . my code
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: elem.getTextContext().getBytes() where is this coming from? You need to get the bytes from ByteArrayOutput stream where you saved the object i.e bos.toByteArray()

Comment: I apologize I could've been more specific. I'm throwing around Text from within DOM elements. `elem` is an input to the "method" `getTextContext()` retrieves the text from within the XML brackets.

Comment: Do you serialize and deserialize using exactly the same JVM (including version)? Sometimes serialization formats change without warning between versions.

Comment: Yes, it's all in the same run. I'm in an Eclipse debug session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hex- or base64-encode the serialised data before putting it into the text node, and decode it before deserializing. Text nodes are Strings, and String is not a container for binary data.

But I don't understand the underlying problem. There are standard ways and standard APIs for representing certificates in XML, and this isn't it.

Comment: I did just discover Base64.encodeBase64String and the Decode block needed to regenerate the Certificate using the CertificateFactory class. I am completely new to Java and have no idea what those APIs are.  Any help?